# How to integrate dialogflow with instagram

Tags: dialogflow-es, instagram-api, chatbot

I wanted to create an Instagram chatbot but I can't find a way to connect Dialogflow and Instagram is there a way to do so? Even if using another chatbot rather than Dialogflow?

Comment: Instagram doesn't have an public api. What bot do you want to built

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found was by using the following android app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tkstudio.autoresponderforig&hl=en
This requires to have your phone ON and Connected to internet all time tho to work
but untill they release an official api I think this is all I have.